# Force JPA entity field type to BLOB

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

In an existing Java EE application there is a JPA entity which contains a string array as a field. Bad, but it is what it is. There are no annotations for it whatsoever and running the application results in Hibernate (on JBoss EAP 6.1 Alpha and MySQL 5.6) storing it as `TINYBLOB`. This obviously fails as soon as the string array contains more than a couple values but yet it works fine as long as the array is not too big.

Is there any way to force via JPA 2 (not Hibernate!) annotation that the field is treated as BLOB instead of `TINYBLOB`?

Using the following will actually create a column of type `BLOB` during setup but when trying to store an instance of the entity it still fails with

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String"
```

Field annotation definition:

```
@Lob
@Column(columnDefinition = "blob")
```

Comment: You should remove your `@Column` annotation or instead you should have a `@Column(columnDefinition = "clob")`, since you want a [variable-length character large object string](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35137_01/doc.32/e18460/oracle_db2_compared.htm#RPTID114).

Comment: @aribeiro but I can't - then all my existing entries are broken.

Comment: Then what about creating a new field annotated with `@Column(columnDefinition = "clob")` that is used gradually from now, and marking the other one as `@Deprecated`? You could change your code so that all updates and new inserts would reference the new field and then there will come a point where is safe to remove your `blob` field.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are on a write way. To avoid ClassCastException try to add converter calss and serialize it manually. Add annotation `@Convert(converter = YoursConvertor.class)` and implement convertor class, something like this:

```
public class YoursConvertor implements AttributeConverter<String[], String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String[] meta) {
         String concatString = "";
         //... some concatinantion etc
         return concatString;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        String[] result = null;
        if (dbData != null && dbData.length() > 0) {
            //... unconcat
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Maybe it must be String[], byte[] - you should try